# "Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined" in attempt to use dotenv in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

In the repository https://github.com/khpeek/trailmaps, I have an example of a Google Map created with `react-google-maps` in which the `googleMapUrl` prop contains my Google Maps API key. In accordance with 12-factor principles, I would like to move this API key into a `.env` file and interpolate it into the URL.

I'm trying to follow the instructions of the [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) module (which comes together with `create-react-app`), and have attempted the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MapWithGroundOverlay from './components/groundOverlay';
require('dotenv').config()

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Custom Overlay</h1>
          <h1 className="App-title">{`The API key is ${process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY}`}</h1>

        </header>
        <MapWithGroundOverlay
          googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBimnrhiugaGSNN8WnsjpzMNJcrH_T60GI&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In the root directory, I've created a `.env` file where I define the `GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY`. However, if I `npm start` the app and go to `localhost:3000`, I get that `process` is undefined:

[image]

According to [Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239060/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined), Node.js code must be run by the Node process, not the browser; presumably, this is what I'm doing wrong. I find that answer a bit high-level to immediately apply here, however. Clearly, `dotenv` should be usable with `create-react-app` or it wouldn't be bundled with it, but am I supposed to use it for this example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dotenv is not intended for browser runtimes. I would suggest adding custom environment variables outlined in the library's documentation.

https://github.com/khpeek/trailmaps#adding-custom-environment-variables

Prefixing the variable with `REACT_APP_` should work as intended.