# Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined Github Personal access token issue

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-pages, github-api, github-actions

I want to add my github personal access token(for authenticating github graphql api) to my code but github keeps removing it from developer settings as soon as it is deployed. i tried adding it as an environment variable by adding it to secrets and declaring it under `env:` in the github actions CI script and then called it in the code using `process.env.PA_TOKEN` but it stil doesn't authenticate although i get a different error message in the console now saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined`. What am i doing wrong?

Note: The token works fine locally before it is removed from developer settings after deployment

Github action workflow

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the action will run. 
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the main branch
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

 # A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      # Runs a single command using the runners shell
      - name: Run a one-line script
      run: echo Hello, world!

      # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: Run a multi-line script
      run: |
        echo Add other actions to build,
        echo test, and deploy your project.
      env: 
        PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

Code implementation

```
const variables = {
  githubToken: process.env.PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  githubLogin: username
}
```

Comment: Could you share your github actions workflow and your code implementation?

Comment: @GuiFalourd added them in the edits

Comment: Did you try adding the [setup/node](https://github.com/actions/setup-node) action to your workflow to test if the error was the same? Otherwise, here is [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239060/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined)  that might also help.