# JavaScript Uncaught ReferenceError token is not defined

Tags: javascript, github, github-actions

How do you properly implement/declare environment variables (containing an access token) from  github actions in your .js script without getting an Uncaught ReferenceError?

Comment: Did you try using `process.env.VARIABLE_NAME` after setting the variable as ENV on your github action workflow?

Comment: @GuiFalourd Yes I did but got `Uncaught ReferenceError process is not defined`

Comment: I'm not familiar with Node, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239060/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined) could help.