# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined when calling createRxDatabase in aurelia app

Tags: javascript, webpack, aurelia, rxdb

I am trying to use rxdb as a store for my aurelia app. I have not found a plugin that implements this aleady, so start writing my own solution. I am using aurelia-cli 2.0.3, aurelia-loader-nodejs 1.1.0 and aurelia-webpack-plugin 5.0.3 with rxdb 11.3.0.

The problem I am running into is that as soon as I call createRxDatabase I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: process is not defined" in the browser console. I tried to follow the recipe given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66367137/4415526 but this result in the following webpack-dev-server warning: "DefinePlugin: Conflicting values for 'process.env.NODE_ENV'"

Any clues how I can please rxdb?