# ReferenceError: proccess is not defined

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, yarnpkg

I am importing from .env using const EXAMPLE_VAR = process.env.EXAMPLE_VAR
This is in a config file, when I run a script which fetches data from the config I get this error:

ReferenceError: proccess is not defined

I think I need to install something, how do I fix this?

I tried running yarn add proccess, that gave me this error:
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/proccess: Not found".

Comment: You should use library "dotenv", check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239060/uncaught-referenceerror-process-is-not-defined

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use "process" instead of "proccess", my mistake.